# KStream-KTable join, message ordering

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have the following two messages on topicA with the same key

1. message1: (k, A1)   (received at time t=0)
2. message2: (k, A2)   (received at time t=5)

and the topology

```
KStream<Integer, A> streamA = builder.stream(topicA);
KTable<Integer, B> tableB = builder.table(topicB);

streamA.leftJoin(tableB, (a, b) -> myJoiner(a,b)).to(topicAB);
```

Let's say that `myJoiner(a1, b)` takes 100 time units and `myJoiner(a2, b)` takes 10 time units. In which order will the messages appear on topicAB?

What I'm trying to figure out is whether stream.leftJoin(table, (k,v)->f(k,v)) is a blocking operation **when stream, table and k** are the same.? (In my example this would mean myJoiner(a1, b) would appear first around time t=100 and myJoiner(a2,b) would appear second around time t=110).  Or is it async (this would mean myJoiner(a2,b) would appear first around time t=15 and myJoiner(a1,b) second around time t=100)

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join is execute "sync" and order is guaranteed.

> In my example this would mean myJoiner(a1, b) would appear first around time t=100 and myJoiner(a2,b) would appear second around time t=110

Yes, this is exactly how it's executed.